# How to specify dist folder as source for publishing lib to npm registry from NX monorepo?

Tags: monorepo, nx-monorepo

I'm new for monorepos and especially NX. At the moment I'm trying to create a lib and publish it to npm registry. For that I use NX console to generate publishable lib and publish it to npm registry.

The problem: the source code published to npm registry instead of from `/dist/my-lib`.

It's not clear what should I need to setup so that I can use NX console `nx-release-publish` to publish code from `dist/my-lib` to npm registry?

I tried to google but with no success. I have the most basic setup of a lib and NX and believe that sotheming should be added to `project.json` inside `my-lib` folder.

```
{
  "name": "@my-lib/utils",
  "$schema": "../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "utils/src",
  "projectType": "library",
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/vite:build",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/utils",
        "generatePackageJson": true
      }
    },
    "publish": {
      "command": "node tools/scripts/publish.mjs @my-lib/utils {args.ver} {args.tag}",
      "dependsOn": ["build"]
    },
    "lint": {
      "executor": "@nx/eslint:lint",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"]
    }
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

If I manually publish from `dist/my-lib` then everything fine, but I'd like to make `nx-release-publish` do the job.